# How to BFS on a graph where each node is the instance of the class Node and I could not modify the class Node?

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have a graph where each node is the instance of the class `Node`. I couldn't modify
the class `Node` also I have to run BFS through the graph. How would I be able to keep track of if a node is visited? I can't use a dictionary as the key of the dictionary must be immutable.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Comment: are there circular paths in your graph? if so you need a unique identifier to check if the node has been visited. You can try multiple approaches, you could add the nodes in a queue and once the node is visited you add the children and delete the parent from the graph so you wont visit it again. If it is just a binary tree then you simply push and pop from a queue till there are no more elements in the queue

Comment: Yeah! I realized, I actually don't need to keep track of if a node is visited after I started implementing. I think the approach you suggested at the end will work for any tree not necessarily a binary tree. Thanks for the comment

Comment: references to Node instances are immutable since they are just the addres of the Node instance. You can use them as keys.